# Formulate two matrices A B such that B*A won't equal A*B

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

FIRST YEAR LINEAR ALGEBRA LEVEL~

So I had a practice question as me to find a 2x2 matrices $A,B$ such that $AB \neq BA$ and I just put a random matrix and altered one of the signs on the top-left value and of course it worked relatively easy, but is there a formulaic approach I should take? I'm not aware of any, from my lectures.

Comment: Have you tried, like any matrices? Most matrices have this property. (I use the term most subjectively, but I'm sure you know what I mean).

Comment: Sorry I accidentally pressed post when I wasn't ready - here it is now.

Comment: There's no need for a formulaic method. What you'll find more and more as you progress in math is that most interesting problems have no formulaic method.

Comment: Oh...so my approach of 99% winging a couple numbers with a dash of intuition that it can't be the exact same vector was enough lol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a systematic approach: Let $A= \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{bmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z& t \end{bmatrix}$.

Then 
$$AB= \begin{bmatrix} ax+bz & ay+bt \\ cx+dz& cy+dt \end{bmatrix}\\
BA= \begin{bmatrix} ax+cy & bx+dy \\ az+ct&bz+dt \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, you must seek an entry where the $AB,BA$ have different expressions, which in this case is all. Pick such an entry, lets say $1,1$ and make sure you pick humbers such that 
$$ax+bz \neq ax+cy$$

Comment: I guess this is my intuition put into formulas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to construct many such examples:

$$A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}, B=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}$$

$$AB=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}, BA=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Edit: When I posted this answer, OP had not mentioned about a systematic method to getting the answer. I am not aware of any systematic method for the same. However, for any element $g$ in a group $G$, every element outside of $C_G(g)=\{h \in G : hg=gh\}$ will not commute with $g$. In general, $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a group and for any element $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, $BA=AB$ iff $B \in C_G(A)$. Of course, anything outside of $C_G(A)$ will not commute. There is no method, of which I am aware of which finds the centraliser of an element of a group in general.

Comment: Note that OP has found such pairs, but rather is looking for a systematic approach to finding an answer. This is not an answer.

Comment: @DonThousand The OP had not edited his answer by then.

Comment: Not true, look at the time stamps.